# convert blackberry Bitmap to (MIDP) Image

Tags: blackberry, graphics, midp

I have a MIDP application using GameCanvas, and I'm using this sequence to get scaled image as javax.microedition.lcdui.Image for rendering into the canvas:

1. Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(data from file)
2. bitmap.scaledInto(largerBitmap..)
3. largerBitmap.getARGB(..)
4. Image.createRGBImage(..)

The obvious disadvantage of this is that consumes a lot of memory, especially at the moment when pulling RGB data from (large) scaled bitmap to a (large) buffer to create Image from it. Performance is also not very good, either due to memory usage or wrong approach - dont' know.

Is there a more efficient way to do what I want? Thank you!